# Safari can't handle animation loop of 200 objects

Tags: for-loop, d3.js, safari, transition

my code works fine in chrome, mozilla, both windows and android, but it always crash on safari ios (iPad and IPhone), right before the animation loop starts

```
$button.on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {

       for ( i = 0; i <= 200; i++ ){

       var angle = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;

       var radius = Math.random()*115;

       var posx = Math.cos(angle)*radius + 390;
       var posy = Math.sin(angle)*radius + 600;

       var svg = d3.select('#container')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 560)
        .attr('height',850)
        .style('position', 'absolute')

       var g = svg
        .append('g')
        .style('stroke', '#262626')
        .style('stroke-width', 2)
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(280,240) scale(0.01)');

       g.each(function(){
        d3.select(this)
        .raise()
        .transition()
        .duration((Math.random() * 4000) + 3000)
        .ease(d3.easeExp)
        .style('opacity' , 1)
        .attr('transform', 'translate('+ posx +','+ posy +') scale(0.15)');
       });

       g.selectAll('path')
        .data(pathdata) // path data variable, contain svg paths
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', d => d.d ) // path data variable
        .style('fill', 'white' );

    } //endforloop
},14500)
}
```

And when I change the condition of for loop to `i <= 10` , (I'm not testing yet the maximum object limit Safari can handle) then it works fine on Safari. I wonder, how could I make 200 objects work properly in Safari??

Comment: What this code does is appending 200 SVGs to the page, one over the other (absolute positioning). Why are you doing that?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ah so that's the problem. thanks. still laggy, but it works